# Azure NodeJS - query all documents with stored procedure

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to call a stored procedure in an azure function which does a query of 'SELECT * from Events c WHERE c.state = "0". When I run the code below, it says PartitionKey value must be supplied for this operation. I have thousands and thousands of partition keys, and I need to query every single document. How would I go about doing this? I read about enabling cross partition, but I can't find where to put that. Is it in the Azure function or Stored Procedure? Thanks

```
client.executeStoredProcedure(databaseUrl + "/colls/Events/sprocs/Events_FindDocs", "null",
    (err, results) => {
        if(err){ 
            context.log(err);
        } else {
            context.log(results);
        }            
    });
```

Comment: I tried to put it in the query in the stored procedure but still getting same error

        let query = {
            query: 'SELECT * from Events c WHERE c.state = "0"',
        };
        collection.queryDocuments(collection("Events").getSelfLink(), query, {         enableCrossPartitionQuery: true }, (err, results) => {
            if(err){
                response.setBody(err);
            } else {
                response.setBody(results);
            }        
        });

Answer (score 1):

Stored procedures cannot run across partitions.

They are partition specific so you won't be able to query everything in a stored procedure if your collection is partitioned.

From the documentation:

"If the collection the stored procedure is registered against is a single-partition collection, then the transaction is scoped to all the documents within the collection. If the collection is partitioned, then stored procedures are executed in the transaction scope of a single partition key. Each stored procedure execution must then include a partition key value corresponding to the scope the transaction must run under."

Learn more about Stored Procedures [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/programming)